# How to send messages to multiple users via bot to individually irrespective of others in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, text-based, multiple-users

So, I'm making a text based game and I want that whenever a user types a command my bit DMS the user and starts the story for that user. I'm not sure how to do this for multiple users. Like if a game has already been initiated and someone else wants to start a new one they should be able to irrespective to the progress of the user that is already playing

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? We do not code all of this for you. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Well since you haven't provided any code it will have to be a description based answer.

For storing data in cache use a `dictionary`

```py
data = {}

...

data[member.id] = {level: 0, money: 0}
```

This would storage the variables level and money inside the `data` variable you can access it with `data[member.id]`.

If you are wanting to store data over long term have a look at databases such as MongoDB or MySQL/MariaDB.

Your code must be async otherwise there will be blocking while things are being calculated. For example, if you are fetching data using `requests` use `aiohttp` or another asynchronous library for it.